# Creating a new language within the Python virtual machine

Tags: python, bytecode, dsl, vm-implementation

Is it possible to create a new language for the Python Virtual Machine? I was reading over http://late.am/post/2012/03/26/exploring-python-code-objects , where the blogger discusses Python code objects. In it, he discusses a disassembly of a code object into bytecode and what the symbols in it mean.

This made me think there could be alternative ways to construct this bytecode. I was curious about the ability to create a sandboxed language within Python bytecode so that Python could load it up. Using Python itself for sandboxing seems darn near impossible, but this appears to make a pathway for another implementation language.

Where would I start if I wanted to pursue this venture? What might be a better approach, and where would I find more on other approaches?

Comment: Interesting question but not really a SO type question.

Comment: I am fairly certain you could, but it would probably end up being a large project.

Comment: @Iguananaut , then what sort of question would it be?

Comment: I've flagged this for migration to Programmers. And I'd build it on top of PyPy's [sandboxing feature](http://pypy.org/features.html).

Comment: You can look at [how why did it](https://github.com/whymirror/unholy). It's probably a big hack, but it used to work

Comment: @NiklasB., you should put that in answer form. That appears to be precisely the sort of thing I'd be looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Why the lucky stiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_the_lucky_stiff) once [hacked together](https://github.com/whymirror/unholy) a script that would compile Ruby code into Python bytecode. I remember that it worked well for simple Ruby scripts. You can look at the sources to see how he did it.

**EDIT**: So what he does is let the Ruby VM generate Ruby bytecode, than translate that bytecode to Python. Could still be interesting to see how the Python bytecode is assembled :)

Answer (score 2):

I think a good place to start would be [ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), here's a Lisp implementation using ply: http://www.juanjoconti.com.ar/files/python/mini-lisp/

I'm not sure if ply can generate syntax trees using Python's [ast](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module, but it should be possible.