# Are there other languages that target the Python Virtual Machine?

Tags: python, bytecode, vm-implementation

It seems that a pretty significant fraction of new languages that come out run either on the JVM or the CLR. Presumably high on the list of advantages to doing so are 1) access to libraries and 2) portability, especially with Java. Has anyone attempted to do the same for Python? The closest I can find digging around is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771312/creating-a-new-language-within-the-python-virtual-machine):

> Why the lucky stiff once hacked together a script that would compile Ruby code into Python bytecode. I remember that it worked well for simple Ruby scripts. You can look at the sources to see how he did it.
>
> EDIT: So what he does is let the Ruby VM generate Ruby bytecode, than translate that bytecode to Python. Could still be interesting to see how the Python bytecode is assembled :)

BTW, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441824/java-virtual-machine-vs-python-interpreter-parlance) an interesting thread about whether Python has a "VM" in the same sense that Java does or an "interpreter." In sum, I think for the purposes of this question it's reasonable to consider Python to have a VM.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148959/why-arent-there-other-programming-languages-that-compile-to-python-bytecode

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *And* the current title encourages list answers.

Comment: Why is this a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com? [The documentation I find](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68386/252342) says that "Programmers - Stack Exchange is for expert programmers who are interested in subjective discussions on software development." This question factual, not subjective.